# Installing pysentiment in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Getting error while installing pysentiment in python 3.7.1

Command used -

```
pip install pysentiment
```

Error

```
Collecting pysentiment
Using cachedhttps://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3d/32/b9822555aeafd9......./pyt=sentiment-0.2.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback(most recent call last):
File "(string)", line 1,(module)
install reg = [e.strip() for e in eopn(path_req).readlines()]
FileNotFoundError[Error 2] No such file or directory:'C:/Users/........pysentiments\requirements.txt
```

Working on Windows 8.1

Comment: Please include the full error message in the body of your question, as well as a description of your setup (OS, which python distribution etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like an error in the `.tar.gz` on PyPi. The file seems to be missing from it. You should be able to install from github:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/hanzhichao2000/pysentiment
```

Comment: This Answer works as needed, hope it works well for OP too. Upvote given.

Answer (score 1):

Download the pysentiment file from this [Pysentiment](https://github.com/hanzhichao2000/pysentiment) and then you can use the command

```
pip install pysentiment-master.zip
```

This worked in my case.